# Python - Cursor - Multiple filters from lists

Tags: python, sql, list, filter, cursor

I want to run a query that filter two columns based on values from two list.

Basically, I want to simulate two filters like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE customers in ("John","Peter") AND customers_numbers IN ('1','2')
```

But the values from customers and customers_number are in two lists. To try this I am making the following code:

```
list1 = ["John","Peter"]
list2 = [1,2]
query_sql = "DELETE FROM vw_bill_details WHERE customers in (%s) and customers_numbers in (%s)" % ','.join(['?'] * len(list1)) % ','.join(['?'] * len(list2))
cursor.execute(query_sql, list1,list2)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    query_sql = "DELETE FROM vw_bill_details WHERE customers in (%s) and customers_numbers in (%s)" % ','.join(['?'] * len(list1)) % ','.join(['?'] * len(list2))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How can I make the above query using python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an error in your query, there's an extra `%` between the two terms instead of a comma. Also, when you use `%` formatting with more than one term, you need to have the entire variables section after the `%` in parentheses:

```
query_sql = "DELETE FROM vw_bill_details WHERE customers in (%s) and customers_numbers in (%s)" % (','.join(['?'] * len(list1)), ','.join(['?'] * len(list2)))
```

Improvements:

1. consider writing your query in a docstring so that it's easier read, write, and debug:

   ```
   query_sql = """DELETE FROM vw_bill_details
   WHERE customers in (%s)
   and customers_numbers in (%s)""" % (
   ','.join(['?'] * len(list1)), ','.join(['?'] * len(list2)))
   ```
2. `str.join()` works on any iterable, including strings, so the `','.join(['?'] * len(list1))` parts could be written as `','.join('?' * len(list1))` - the `?` mark is a single string rather than a list with a single element.
3. There is potential for matching the wrong records: the `WHERE customers in ("John","Peter") AND customers_numbers IN ('1','2')` doesn't care/check of 'John' has cust_number 1 or 2. So it could match with a John-2 and a Peter-1, instead of you're intended John-1 and Peter-2.

   Examples of the mismatch can be seen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa7f3/2

   You can avoid this mismatch by specifying the name and number matches each:

   ```sql
   WHERE (customers = 'John' AND customers_numbers = '1')
      OR (customers = 'Peter' AND customers_numbers = '2')
   ```

   which could also be written as as a matching pair:

   ```sql
   WHERE (customers, customers_numbers) = ('John', 1)
   ```

   and you can extend it for multiple options with:

   ```sql
   WHERE (customers, customers_numbers) IN (('John', 1), ('Peter', 2))
   ```

   which is easier to parameterize with `?`s than the extended AND/OR version above.